# TestNG disable some sets of a dataProvider

Tags: java, testng

I have this test, that uses a dataProvider, and I want to only execute one of the 2 runs because one of the tests is expected to fail.

```
@Test(dataProvider = "data")
public void testThatPassesAndFails(boolean test, String whatever) {
    Assert.assertTrue(test);//Once scenario passes, other fails
}

 @DataProvider(name = "data")
 public static Object[][] paramData() {
     return new Object[][] {
         {true, "blah"},
         {false, "blah2"}
     };
 }
```

In reality, we have a custom annotation that ties a test to a test database that tracks expected test failures. For non data-provider tests, we use an `IAnnotationTransformer` and call `annotation.setEnabled(false)` and that works nicely for single instance tests.

However, we have some dataprovider tests that we want to run all but 1 or 2 of the sets of data. Is it possible to disable or remove only some of the invocations? The closest I can get now is implementing `IInvokedMethodListener` and throwing a `SkipException` in the `beforeInvocation` method. This isn't bad, but I'd rather not have the skips in the test results, since they hurt the passing percentage. I know I can use another listener to manipulate the TestNG results too, but that will get messy.

Is there some way using `IAnnotationTransformer` or `IAnnotationTransformer2` to get the parameter values for each iteration of a test that uses a dataProvider, then disable? Even if I can manipulate the dataProvider method to remove the "bad" cases, that would work.

Answer (score 1):

On a high level, here's how you solve this :

1. Add a parameter to your `<suite>` (or) `<test>` tag in your suite xml file which indicates the filtering.
2. Have your test classes implement `IHookable` interface.
3. Within the `IHookable` implementation examine if the parameters being passed by the data provider to the actual test method satisfies the filtering criteria mentioned in (1).
4. If the filtering criteria passes, run the test method else explicitly set the status to `SKIP` and set a custom exception.
5. Build a `TestListenerAdaptor` customization which filters out all the test results whose status is `SKIP` and whose exception is your custom exception.

That should do the trick.

Here's how the test class would look like:

```java
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.IHookCallBack;
import org.testng.IHookable;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.Reporter;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class TestclassSample implements IHookable {
    @Override
    public void run(IHookCallBack callBack, ITestResult testResult) {
        Object[] parameters = callBack.getParameters();
        String runType = parameters[0].toString();
        String expectedInputType = testResult.getTestContext().getCurrentXmlTest().getAllParameters().get("runType");
        if (runType.equalsIgnoreCase(expectedInputType)) {
            callBack.runTestMethod(testResult);
        } else {
            testResult.setStatus(ITestResult.SKIP);
            testResult.setThrowable(new DataSetSkipException("Skipping data set " + Arrays.toString(parameters) ));
        }
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "dp")
    public void testMethod(String inputType, int number) {
        String expectedInputType = Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().getTestContext().getCurrentXmlTest().getAllParameters().get("runType");
        Assert.assertTrue(number > 0);
        Assert.assertEquals(inputType, expectedInputType);
        System.err.println("(" + inputType + ", " + number + ")");
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "dp")
    public Object[][] getData() {
        return new Object[][]{
                {"bad", 100},
                {"good", 500},
                {"good", 600},
                {"good", 200},
                {"new", 300}
        };
    }

    public static class DataSetSkipException extends RuntimeException {
        public DataSetSkipException(String message) {
            super(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's how the listener can look like :

```java
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.ITestNGMethod;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.TestListenerAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class BadResultRemovingListener extends TestListenerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void onFinish(ITestContext testContext) {
        Iterator<ITestResult> skipTestsIterator = testContext.getSkippedTests().getAllResults().iterator();
        List<ITestNGMethod> methodsToRemove = new ArrayList<>();
        while (skipTestsIterator.hasNext()) {
            ITestResult result = skipTestsIterator.next();
            if (result.getThrowable() instanceof TestclassSample.DataSetSkipException) {
                methodsToRemove.add(result.getMethod());
            }
        }
        for (ITestNGMethod method : methodsToRemove) {
            testContext.getSkippedTests().removeResult(method);
        }
    }
}
```

TestNG suite xml file looks like below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="46472511_Suite" parallel="false" verbose="2">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn46472511.BadResultRemovingListener"/>
    </listeners>
    <parameter name="runType" value="good"/>
    <test name="46472511_test1">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn46472511.TestclassSample"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

You may see some awkward results when you run this from within an IDE, but when you run from a build tool such as Maven for e.g., your output would look like below:

```
11:36 $ mvn clean test -DsuiteXmlFile=46472511.xml
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building testbed 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) @ testbed ---

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
...
... TestNG 6.12 by Cédric Beust (cedric@beust.com)
...

(good, 500)
(good, 600)
(good, 200)
Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 2, Time elapsed: 0.313 sec - in TestSuite

Results :

Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.783 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-09-29T11:36:21+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 37M/331M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```